# Add element in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, addition, filereader

I am trying to add a new element to an array list but when I print the structure I get the adress in memory. Any idea?

I read the information from a file and I try to put it in a structure Assignatures which is an in numAssignatures and one ArrayList and assignatura has an string with the name and one integer.

```
public static void llegeixFitxer(Curs[] curs) throws IOException {

    FileReader file = new FileReader("assignatures.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    for (int j=0; j< 5; j++){

        curs[j] = new Curs();
        curs[j].numAssignatures = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i<curs[j].numAssignatures; i++){

            String aux = reader.readLine();
            String[] parts = aux.split("-");
            String assignaturallegida = parts[0];
            int creditsllegits = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].replace(" ",""));

            curs[j].addAssignatura(assignaturallegida,creditsllegits);
        }

        System.out.println(curs[j].getNumAssignatures() + " + " + curs[j].getAssignatures());
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

}

I get this:

```
7 + [model.Assignatura@7eda2dbb, model.Assignatura@6576fe71, model.Assignatura@76fb509a, model.Assignatura@300ffa5d, model.Assignatura@1f17ae12, model.Assignatura@4d405ef7, model.Assignatura@6193b845]
```

Thank you!!

Comment: It looks like your class Assignatura does not have specific toString() method defined

Comment: What is the return type of curs[j].getAssignatures(), add to this return type toString() method

Answer (score 1):

**You have to override the `toString()` method in your `model.Assignatura` class.**

The default implementation of `toString()` would print Fully Qualified class name followed by '@' and the object's hash code in hexadecimal format. That's explaining what you are receiving.